# Passing or sharing data between two components persisted between refresh

Tags: angular

I have a component product-list that basically displays all of my products:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
  <a routerLink="/products/{{ product.url }}" [state]="product">{{ product.name }}</a>
  <p>{{ product.url }}</p>
</div>
```

Each product on this page should open up a product-update component from where I can view, update and delete a product.

I tried passing in the information about a product from the product-list to product-update by using the Angular state attribute. This is how I am retrieving the data in the product-update component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pruduct = window.history.state;
}
```

Everything works but it seems like the data is lost after a page refresh.
I figured I can use local storage to solve this problem but I have a feeling there has to be a better way for such a basic use case. Is state my best option?

Comment: What if product changed between the time you rendered the list and clicked on link to see the product ? In product-update I'd retrieve 'id' param from route and load the product again in ngOnInit. As to answer your question directly you would usually use service to pass data between sibling components

Comment: @IhorBodnarchuk can you point me in the right direction as to how to pass data between sibling components? An example would be great

Comment: Pls refer to official docs https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction but there also answered questions on here as well

Answer (score 0):

Usually on the "Back-end" side there is a version of the service that accepts as input also the id of one of the elements. Could you think of exchanging that id between the product-list and the page where you show the single item, on whose page you then go to call that service (with id in input)?
Something like a `/products/{{id}}` service.

I think this is the best way to manage it. With this approach you can also decide to add informations on the display of the single product and leave the list page with less information.

Another possible solution is to save the entire list of products within the `localStorage` and recall from that list only the product you need, on the single page.

No others solutions come to my mind.

Comment: If I understand your initial solution correctly, I would run into the same issue with id. If I pass in the id from the list component to the update, I would lose it on refresh

Comment: No, because with a refresh you will also reload the input id (in the path) and, with it, you will also call the service "/products/{{id}}".

It is a solution usually adopted.

Comment: this doesn't work in my case as my back end has a completely different url